# Programmatically Auto-Layout Functions

Tags: ios, swift, object

Im having an issue with these two functions. For func 1:

```
  func constrainWidth(width: CGFloat) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
    let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[item(width)]", metrics: ["width" : width], views: ["item" : self])
    self.superview?.addConstraints(constraints)
    return constraints as! [NSLayoutConstraint]
}
```

I get an error at "self.superview?.addConstraints(constraints)" they have a problem with "constraints"
and it says:
 *cannot convert value of type [Any Object] to expected argument type '[NSLayoutConstraint]'*

Here is func 2:

```
 class func constraintsWithVisualFormat(visualFormat: String,  options: NSLayoutFormatOptions, views: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> [AnyObject] {
    return NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(visualFormat, options: options, metrics: nil, views: views)
}
```

I get an error at "return NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(visualFormat, options: options, metrics: nil, views: views)" they have a problem with "views"
and it says: *Cannot convert value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]'

These function don't affect one another, i just need help with them both. I didn't have this problem before, it just came up recently i believe because of the new swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **func 1**:

There is the `options` parameter missing, it doesn't even compile in my XCode. When I add the `options` parameter, it compiles & runs without problems.

For **func 2**:

It tells exactly what is wrong - the parameter you hand over for views is defined as `[NSObject : AnyObject]`, but it has to be `[String: AnyObject]`.

Comment: Your Amazing! I got func 1 to work.
Any suggestions to what i should put for func 2? I got that its suppose to be a string, but I'm not to sure what? or if i need to make views a dictionary and have a key and value?? @TheEye

Comment: Well, you see in func 1 what the content of the views dictionary is - a string key, and a view object. The definition of the function parameter for the views dictionary has to be [String: AnyObject].